# List comprehension: muti-dimension items for each loop

Tags: python, list

I have a function (test_func) and I want to create a list:

```
def test_func(i):
    return [[i, i+1], [i**2, i**3]]
output=[test_func(i) for i in range(5)]
```

The results are as follows:

```
[[[0, 1], [0, 0]],
 [[1, 2], [1, 1]],
 [[2, 3], [4, 8]],
 [[3, 4], [9, 27]],
 [[4, 5], [16, 64]]]
```

How to get the following results:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 8], [3, 4], [9, 27], [4, 5], [16, 64]]
```

Sincerely thank you,

Comment: Every item in your array contains 2 separate pairs, you have to print every pair in each item separately I think

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
output=[v for i in range(5) for v in test_func(i)]
```

This produces:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 8], [3, 4], [9, 27], [4, 5], [16, 64]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument for the `sum` function is what you sum across - so in this case providing `[]`, the sum is performed across lists (extending them, basically). This operation corresponds to flattening the list.

```py
def test_func(i):
    return [[i, i+1], [i**2, i**3]]

output = sum([test_func(i) for i in range(5)], [])
```

Comment: Hey, would you please explain how/why your answer works? It is very nice to see a working code snippet, but you could improve it with an additional explanation :D

Comment: @sjaustirni the second argument for the sum function is what you sum across - so in this case providing `[]`, the sum is performed across lists (extending them, basically). This operation corresponds to flattening the list

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation, thank you! Next time, please, add it to the answer itself. Otherwise, great work, keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Without a function you could use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable((([i, i+1], [i**2, i**3]) for i in range(5))))
```

which gives:

```
[[0, 1],
 [0, 0],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 8],
 [3, 4],
 [9, 27],
 [4, 5],
 [16, 64]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
flat_out = [item for sublist in output for item in sublist]

[[0, 1],
 [0, 0],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 8],
 [3, 4],
 [9, 27],
 [4, 5],
 [16, 64]]
```

or

```
def test_func(i):
    return [[i, i+1], [i**2, i**3]]
output= [k for i in range(5) for k in test_func(i) ]
output
```